# Is there a closed form for multi-step ARIMA/ARMA density forecasts conditioned on initial values?/alternatives to this?

Tags: forecasting, arima, references, density-function, probabilistic-forecasts

I am attempting to create a benchmark for probabilistic forecasting of time series to test other models against and figured that a linear ARIMA/ARMA model would be a good starting point.

I thought that given how much literature there is on these models, that a closed form solution for multi-step density forecasts conditioned on necessary initial values for the lagged variables/errors should be documented somewhere, assuming existence, but haven't been able to find much so far.

So far I have attempted a bit of derivation by hand (which I can post if needed) through recursive substitution on the ARMA(1,1) model, as if there isn't a closed form for the general case, the multi-step ARMA(1,1) density forecasts are what I'm looking for.

I started to see a bit of a pattern potentially emerge in the location and scales of the distributions for increasing forecast horizons, but that could've been incorrect and if there's already a documented closed form, I wouldn't want to risk making a mistake in the algebra of my derivation if I were to pursue this myself.

By "closed form" for the "density forecast", in the ARMA(1,1) case, I mean that I'm wanting a conditional probability density function for $X_{t+n}$ given $X_t$ and $\varepsilon_t$:

$$\hat{f}_{X_{t+n}|X_t, \varepsilon_t}, n \in \mathbb{N_1}.$$

given that for $t \in \mathbb{N_1}$:

$$X_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1X_{t-1} + \alpha_2\varepsilon_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t, \varepsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$$

Also as a related/sub-question, if no closed form is possible even given initial values, and even if so, is there another way to approximate the density of a distribution evaluated at a point from some other representation of the distribution?

Comment: I guess that in Shumway's book or Brockwell and Davis you should find something.

Comment: You can use the Kalman filter to do this (well, assuming that you're conditioning on parameters, which is common in this context).

Comment: @Eryna thanks for the reference! I may have to check those out :)

Comment: @ChrisHaug ooh okay! thanks for the topic reference :) I'll have to look into that. I've heard a bit about Kalman Filters, but haven't read too much on them. Also, thank you for the catch, perhaps I should've specified that the parameters are fixed/are being conditioned on.